# Ubuntu 16.04 Bookworm Install Issues

Tags: software-installation, ebooks

Ubuntu 16.04 and Up Terminal Installation

Follow this link for Bookworm:
  https://babluboy.github.io/bookworm/

Otherwise, here are the terminal commands to satisfy any dependencies from the Git-Hub repository site:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bookworm-team/bookworm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install com.github.babluboy.bookworm
```

Be very certain to install the first repository above and update your sources before you proceed to the commands below.

Note that you cannot install Bookworm without adding the Elementary OS repository and updating your sources to satisfy your dependencies.

Install Bookworm only after adding the Elementary OS repository following the terminal commands below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install com.github.babluboy.bookworm
```

Let me know how this works out for everyone present.

Comment: Just edited and reposted the question. The link to Bookworm did not post correctly. My apologies.

Comment: Are you trying to tell us how to install Bookworm?  I don't see an actual question here but just a set of instructions.  It is not a problem to do a Q&A type where you answer your own question.

Comment: Yes. I was doing some research regarding the install of Bookworm. I followed a link which provided me a solution to share with the community along with the terminal install commands. Should this not be the appropriate forum for such comments, please inform me where in the site I would need to post future shares and how they need to be posted in a specific format. I'm wide open for any instruction here. Thank you very much for informing me of any inconveniences created.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Comment: [Here is a excellent example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) to follow for doing your own Q&A.